# BigQueryIO - Can't use DynamicDestination with CREATE_IF_NEEDED for unbounded PCollection and FILE_LOADS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My workflow : KAFKA -> Dataflow streaming -> BigQuery

Given that having low-latency isn't important in my case, I use *FILE_LOADS* to reduce the costs. I'm using *BigQueryIO.Write* with a *DynamicDestination* (one new table every hour, with the current hour as a suffix).

This BigQueryIO.Write is configured like this :

```
.withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
.withMethod(Method.FILE_LOADS)
.withTriggeringFrequency(triggeringFrequency)
.withNumFileShards(100)
```

The first table is successfully created and is written to. But then the following tables are never created and I get these exceptions:

```
(99e5cd8c66414e7a): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create load job with id prefix 5047f71312a94bf3a42ee5d67feede75_5295fbf25e1a7534f85e25dcaa9f4986_00001_00023, reached max retries: 3, last failed load job: {
  "configuration" : {
    "load" : {
      "createDisposition" : "CREATE_NEVER",
      "destinationTable" : {
        "datasetId" : "dev_mydataset",
        "projectId" : "myproject-id",
        "tableId" : "mytable_20180302_16"
      },
```

For the first table the *CreateDisposition* used is *CREATE_IF_NEEDED* as specified, but then this parameter is not taken into account and *CREATE_NEVER* is used by default.

I also created the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3772) on JIRA.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of Apache Beam's BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.html#CREATE_IF_NEEDED), the method `BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition` requires that a table schema is provided using [the precondition `.withSchema()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withSchema-com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema-) when *CREATE_IF_NEEDED* is used.

As stated also in the [Dataflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io#writing-to-bigquery):

> Note that if you specify CREATE_IF_NEEDED as the CreateDisposition and
>   you don't supply a TableSchema, **the transform may fail at runtime with
>   a *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException* if the target table does not
>   exist.**

The error that documentation states is not the same one as you are receiving (you get `java.lang.RuntimeException`), but according to the `BigQueryIO.Write()` configuration you shared, you are not specifying any table schema, and therefore, if tables are missing, the job is prone to failure.

So as a first measure to solve your issue, you should create the table schema `TableSchema()` that matches the data you will load into BQ, and then use the precondition `.withSchema(schema)` accordingly:

```
List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
// Add fields like:
fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("<FIELD_NAME>").setType("<FIELD_TYPE>"));
TableSchema schema = new TableSchema().setFields(fields);

// BigQueryIO.Write configuration plus:
    .withSchema(schema)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify it because I thought it was not relevant but I do specify a schema, using `.withJsonSchema()`, and it works fine to create the first table.
The problem seems to be that `CREATE_DISPOSITION` is ignored for the other tables than the ones in the first pane. Please see [Jonas' comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3772?focusedCommentId=16387609&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16387609) on the JIRA issue for more details.

Comment: It does look like [how the class `WriteTables` handles panes](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteTables.java#L155) may be related to your issue. That's why I think this question can better be tracked in the Apache Beam forum you shared, as I do not know if there's a way to force that each new table is created in the first pane, so that it can use the defined `CreateDisposition`. Once the question is solved, feel free to post an answer in this post. Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with Beam 2.6.0 and 2.9.0. I am also able to create the first table, but not any of the following. The error message is exactly the same as in the original post. I have commented in the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3772?focusedCommentId=16739264&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16739264) post with a sample code that fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Beam: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3772

It's still open in version 2.27

I developed a workaround : I wrote a custom PTransform which creates an empty table before BigqueryIO.Write stage. It uses the bigquery java client. You can see it here to get inspired:
https://gist.github.com/matthieucham/85459eff5fdea8d115be520e2dd5ccc1